# Trello - is it possible to see a board as it was at a given date?

Tags: trello, trello-cards, trello-boards

Apologies for the phrasing, I can't think of a better way to describe it. I'm trying to generate some reports and I'd like to see a given board as it was at a specific point in time. I tried using time filters (before/since) but it doesn't give me the right result; cards removed from the board after the fact are not shown. I'm using UTC time for this, which unless I'm mistaken, is the same used internally by Trello.

I know it's possible to generate something using card actions, but I'm wondering if there's a more straightforward way?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Trello doesn't have a view board as on a specific day feature. I do believe you can use the `created:day` / `edited:day` [search operators](http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/1145462-searching-for-cards-all-boards-) to return what cards were created/edited, but that's about it.